# how to use and get working org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi osgi bundle

Tags: java, xml

I just upgraded my Apache POI libs from 3.9 to 4.0.1, also using the Apache bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi which has many changes and dependencies. I'm on my way to fulfilling the dependencies, keep running in to missing constraint issues.  Does anyone have a working Apache POI implementation using org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/4.0.0_1 ??? I'm stuck on osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xml.security.signature)

I'm getting this Error:

```
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi/4.0.0_1 in feature(s) fadec-application-1.0.0: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.apache.servicemix.bundles.poi [303]: Unable to resolve 303.0: missing requirement [303.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.xml.security.signature)
```

How to use and get working in karaf osgi container.  too many unneeded depenedencies and missing dependencies.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there are no except 3.9_2 that work or are successfully deployable to a OSGI karaf container.  you need to build your own.  here is a start.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ge.ip.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-bundle</artifactId>
<version>3.1.7</version>

<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>POI OSGi-Bundle</name>

<description>This OSGi bundle wraps poi, poi-ooxml, poi-ooxml-schemas and poi-scratchpad jar files.</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
<!--     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
        <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
        <version>1.06</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>stax</groupId>
        <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
 <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Export-Package>
                    org.apache.poi.*;-split-package:=merge-first
                </Export-Package>
                    <!--
                    One important thing to note: if you are not exporting a package, you add it to the Private-Package instruction.
                    Otherwise, the classes inside the package will not be copied to your bundle, as the default value of this instruction is empty.
                    ;-split-package:=merge-first,com.graphbuilder.curve  || com.graphbuilder.geom, schemasMicrosoftComOfficeExcel.*
                    -->
                    <Private-Package>
                        org.apache.commons.*,
                        org.apache.xmlbeans.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.curve.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.geom.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.math.*,
                        com.graphbuilder.org.apache.harmony.awt.gl.*
                    </Private-Package>
                    <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                    <!-- <Import-Package>*</Import-Package> -->
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <id>copy-dependencies</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
               </goals>
            </execution>
         </executions>
     </plugin>
 </plugins>

</build>

</project>
```